# Replace the values that are returned from a SQL query

Tags: sql, excel, odbc

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
    BM.BOOKING_NO, 
    BM.REF, 
    BM.ACCOUNT, 
    BM.NAME, 
    BM.STATUS, 
    BM.DATE_IN, 
    BM.DATE_OUT, 
    BM.TOTNIGHTS, 
    BM.ROOM_NO, 
    BM.TOTFRGN, 
    REC.PRICE_CATAGORY
FROM
    BOOKMASTER BM LEFT JOIN RECEIVABLES REC ON BM.ACCOUNT = REC.ACCOUNT_NO
WHERE
    BM.STATUS = 'CHECK IN'
```

The `REC.PRICE_CATAGORY` column will return one of three values: `1`, `2` or `3`.

I want to replace it with the following values:

- If `1`, I want it to read `'YES'`
- If `2`, I want it to read `'NO'`
- If `3`, I want it to read `'MAYBE'`

My results return to an Excel spreadsheet and so the lazy way would be to do a `VLOOKUP`, but I would prefer to do it inside the query.

I feel like this is a job for a `CASE` statement, but I am not 100% sure how to construct the query

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did the `50 %` in the question itself by mentioning `case` expression , but you don't know the implementation so, you can do :

```
SELECT BM.BOOKING_NO, BM.REF, BM.ACCOUNT, BM.NAME, BM.STATUS, BM.DATE_IN, BM.DATE_OUT, BM.TOTNIGHTS, BM.ROOM_NO, BM.TOTFRGN, 
       (CASE REC.PRICE_CATAGORY 
             WHEN 1 THEN 'YES'
             WHEN 2 THEN 'NO'
             WHEN 3 THEN 'MAYBE'
             ELSE 'Whatever you want to print'
        END) AS PRICE_CATAGORY 
FROM BOOKMASTER BM LEFT JOIN 
     RECEIVABLES REC 
     ON BM.ACCOUNT = REC.ACCOUNT_NO
WHERE BM.STATUS = 'CHECK IN';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the column as string values, then:

SELECT id, name, CASE WHEN hide = 0 THEN 'false' ELSE 'true' END AS hide
  FROM anonymous_table
If the DBMS supports BOOLEAN, you can use instead:

SELECT id, name, CASE WHEN hide = 0 THEN false ELSE true END AS hide
  FROM anonymous_table